# Spring-data-neo4j VS neo4j API

Tags: neo4j, spatial, spring-data-neo4j

I started building my app using neo4j API and it was working fine. Now I'm trying to integrate Spatial plugin to make spatial queries but I've seen there's a Spring-data integration for both neo4j and spatial.

I change the code from my project to run it on Spring-data but now I'm getting multiple errors because I haven't SDN Metadata in my graph db.

My question is: Is worth to migrate to spring data and rebuild all my db polluting it with SDN metadata just to use this Spring-data spatial and entity mapping, which I haven't ever needed, just to make spatial queries or does it work fine with the neo4j API?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a question that can be generally answered! Using Spring Data for Neo4j CAN lead to a better code structure but in the end it depends on your personal preference! If you're already using the Spring framework in your project it might fit better also using it for neo4j.. What generally can be said is that Spring brings a lot of code in the game and so is slower than a good self made implementation.